# Where can I find a time series dataset on patient waiting lists for hospitals (or, some other healthcare related time series dataset)?

Tags: time-series

I found [some](https://data.world/datagov-uk/a593a0b3-29ef-48f2-b2b2-ceb83d841a3c) on data.world which is a set of data from a conglomerate of hospitals in Ireland. However, this set is not useful to me because it is split between many hospitals for only a period of twelve months. There are many records but the time lags are too few (only twelve). I need a dataset of at least about 200 time observations, where each record is an observation at some time T, with each time interval being identical.